# How do I make an li element editable after double clicking the text (in vanilla Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, dom-events, html-lists

I am creating a to do list project in vanilla Javascript and have been trying to figure out how to edit an li item in the list on a double click mouse event. I want to be able to have the original text in the textbox after double clicking and update with the new text after clicking away from the textbox or pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>.

This is something I tried to write. Please let me know what I am doing wrong or if there is a better approach to the problem.

```
editInput function() {
var todosUl = document.querySelector('ul');
todosUl.addEventListener('dblclick', function(event) {
   if (event.target.childNodes[0]) {
     var originalInput = event.target.childNodes[0];
     var editingInput = document.createElement("input");
     editingInput.type = 'text';
     parent = editingInput.parentNode;
     parent.replaceChild(originalInput, editingInput);
   }
```

Please no jQuery!

Answer (score 0):

you can use contenteditabe property of html, and add the property on click to the desired element:

```js
Object.prototype.insertAfter = function (newNode) { 
  this.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, this.nextSibling);
};

document.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
    if(e.currentTarget.activeElement.className === 'content'){
      if ((e.keyCode || e.which) == 13) {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        var ce = document.createAttribute('contenteditable');
        ce.value = "true";
        var cl = document.createAttribute('class');
        cl.value='content';
        li.setAttributeNode(ce);
        li.setAttributeNode(cl);
        e.currentTarget.activeElement.insertAfter(li);
        li.focus();
        return false;
      }else{
        return true;
      }
      
    }
  
  });
```

```css
li {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li contenteditable="true" class="content">
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is there a way to make it so that when you press enter, it will save the new text? Right now if I press enter, it creates a new line.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it out.